# Having trouble with findAll statements

Tags: beautifulsoup, findall

Trying to dig into html to get color.

```
color  = soup.find_all('a', {'class' : 'logsss_event_cl itemAttr current'})
print(color)
```

What I get is:

```
[<a class="logsss_event_cl itemAttr current" data-logsss-const-value="{'x': 'change_color'}" data-value="WHITE" href="javascript:void(0)" title="**WHITE**"><img src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2019/04/24thumb-img/1556072536277922126.jpg"/></a>, <a class="logsss_event_cl itemAttr current" data-logsss-const-value="{'x': 'change_size'}" data-value="3X" href="javascript:void(0)" title="3X">3X</a>] href
```

What I want is "white"

Answer (score 0):

Your search is returning all values for `links` with the class `logsss_event_cl itemAttr current`. If you want the `text` value, you can accomplish that using the following code:

```
# first, get all values for colo
color_all = soup.find_all('a', {'class' : 'logsss_event_cl itemAttr current'})

# Next, only get text
color_text = [x.get('title') for x in color_all]
```

Comment: I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Can you past the results for `color[0]`?

Comment: Where would I put color[0]

Comment: I'm just curious for the output so I can help answer your Q.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="logsss_event_cl itemAttr current" title="WHITE" data-value="WHITE" data-logsss-const-value="{'x': 'change_color'}"><img src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2019/04/24thumb-img/1556072536277922126.jpg" xpath="1" style=""></a>

Comment: That did it. Thank you!